# Image doesn't show after onChange function in IE

Tags: javascript, forms, select, html

Basically, I have made a function that selects a certain image to display depending on which option the user selects from the drop down menu which works great on Chrome and Firefox! But unfortunately not IE. I have no idea why and would appreciate anyone's wisdom on this matter.

CSS:

```
    #texture img {
        width: 395px;
        height: 288px;
        border: 1px solid #3d3d3d;
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
    function newTexture() {
            var textureName = '<img src="'+document.worktopForm.worktopColour.value+'.jpg">';
            document.getElementById("texture").innerHTML = textureName;     
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form name="worktopForm">
    <select name="worktopColour" onChange="newTexture();">
        <option value="none" selected></option>
        <option value="starGalaxy">Star Galaxy(Band One)</option>
        <option value="seravalle">Seravalle(Band Two)</option>
        <option value="balmoralFineGrain">Balmoral Fine Grain(Band Three)</option>
        <option value="nutYellow">Nut Yellow(Band Four)</option>
       </select>

    <div id="texture"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Add a JSFiddle and maybe we can help :)

Comment: Using JSFiddle on IE will be different from using it on Chrome or Firefox by any chance? It's not that it isn't working the images just aren't showing up on IE for some odd reason!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lukedt/Rg4Xa/

Comment: Your code works fine in IE9. Is this limited to some versions of IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE only fires the onchange event when the element loses focus, which isn't until you click the button, tab out or click somewhere on the screen...
i prefer u to use jquery or some other library for  event handling...

try this ....
give selectbox an id....say "worktopColour" ....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#worktopColour").bind(($.browser.msie ? "click" : "change"), function() {
    var textureName = '<img src="'+document.worktopForm.worktopColour.value+'.jpg">';
        document.getElementById("texture").innerHTML = textureName;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have go various other onChange events that fire off functions that work within this form which work fine on IE and the image appear on Chrome on Firefox. So I have a feeling it's something to do with the function, HTML or CSS that IE doesn't like? I'm not sure what though..